# jQuery - After 3rd party page set value, trigger the event from main page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Recently, I've tried to concatenate a 3rd-party subpage which will set a value for the main page text input by id. However, the main question here is: How can I trigger events like `onchange` after getting that value for the next step? The problem is the 3rd-party page. It can not be changed. Could anyone suggest a solution for this case? It is developed by JQuery.

```
$('#add').unbind().click(function() {
    window.open('3rd party URL'); //set value to id="temp"
});

$('#temp').change(function() {
    // do something...
})
```

Comment: Please share code you have tried to get help

Comment: forgot to post it. have already shared the code,

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to run the code inside the `change` method after the `id="temp"` value is set. You can use `$('#temp').trigger('change')` for that.

Comment: during the 3rd party page. The user will select the data util click confirm button. so if I add the $('#temp').trigger('change')  after window.open(). It will be no value. I have to wait for the window closing.

Comment: So you need to get data from the 3rd party page? What page is it and what is the method the data is being sent by on it?

Comment: I didn't descrip clearly. sorry about that

Comment: If I'm right. The 3rd party page did something like val() by certain id which is #temp. the only thing I could do is create a input text with that id.